# MySQL query to find Products that were sold on both the days

Tags: mysql

I have to write a MySQL query: 
Find products that were sold on both the days (01-JUL-11 and 02-JUL-11) and number of total product sold.

The table looks like:

```
Date, Order_id, Product_id, Quantity
'01-JUL-11',O1,P1,5
'01-JUL-11',O2,P2,2
'01-JUL-11',O3,P3,10
'01-JUL-11',O4,P1,10
'02-JUL-11',O5,P3,5
'02-JUL-11',O6,P4,6
'02-JUL-11',O7,P1,2
'02-JUL-11',O8,P5,1
'02-JUL-11',O9,P6,2
'02-JUL-11',O10,P2,4
```

Output:

```
P1 17
P2 6
P3 15
```

So far I have tried is:

```
SELECT PRODUCT_ID, TOTAL FROM
(SELECT PRODUCT_ID, COUNT(PRODUCT_ID) AS COUNTER, SUM(TOTAL) TOTAL FROM
(Select ORDER_DAY, PRODUCT_ID, SUM(QUANTITY) AS TOTAL
FROM ORDERS
GROUP BY ORDER_DAY, PRODUCT_ID) ALIAS_1
GROUP BY PRODUCT_ID) ALIAS_2
WHERE COUNTER > 1;
```

It gives the right output but I think it can be optimized.

Comment: very unclear what you are asking here

Comment: @Drew I made the edit. Let me know if it is still unclear.

Comment: @Raj, I think a HAVING clause would make it optimized, check my answer for reference

Answer (score 0):

select Product_id, sum(*) sum_total from orders
where id in (
select distinct a.Product_id from orders a inner join orders b on a.Product_id=b.Product_id and a.date!=b.date )
group by Product_id

Answer (score -1):

If the table only has those two dates then your query should work. The only difference is if there are other dates on the table you should specify which dates you want.

see the sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f700a5/6

```
Select `PRODUCT_ID`, SUM(`QUANTITY`)
FROM ORDERS
WHERE `ORDER_DAY` = '01-JUL-11' OR `ORDER_DAY` = '02-JUL-11'
GROUP BY PRODUCT_ID;
```

Comment: Find products that were sold on both the days, I dont think your query works fine.

Comment: You only want the products that sold on July 1st and 2nd?

Comment: If the product only sold on one of the given days then you do not want it in your result?

Comment: The questions asks for 'both'  and not either of them. Hence, this query is wrong.

Comment: @abhishekkumar You're right but he never answered back when I asked for clarification so this answer was never updated.

Answer (score -1):

Right Query for this:

```
SELECT `PRODUCT_ID`, SUM(`QUANTITY`)
FROM ORDERS
WHERE `ORDER_DAY` = '01-JUL-11' OR `ORDER_DAY` = '02-JUL-11'
GROUP BY `PRODUCT_ID`
HAVING COUNT(`ORDER_DAY`) > 1;
```

This will give you the right result.

Answer (score -1):

This is the simplest answer

```
 SELECT PRODUCT_ID, SUM ( QUANTITY)
 FROM CUSTOMER
 WHERE DATE = '01-01-2001'
 GROUP BY PRODUCT_ID 
 MINUS
 SELECT PRODUCT_ID, SUM ( QUANTITY) 
 FROM CUSTOMER
 WHERE DATE = '01-02-2001'
 GROUP BY PRODUCT_ID;
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this out:

```
    select product_id, sum(quantity) as total
    from orders
    group by product_id
    having count(order_day) > 1;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT PRODUCT_ID,SUM(quantity) FROM ORDERS
GROUP BY PRODUCT_ID
HAVING count(distinct Order_date) > 1
```

Answer (score -1):

--Products sold on both the days

```
SELECT PRODUCT_ID, DATE, COUNT(*)
FROM ORDERS
WHERE DATE IN ('01-JUL-11', '02-JUL-11')
GROUP BY PRODUCT_ID, DATE
ORDER BY PRODUCT_ID, DATE
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

--Quantities sold on both days

```
SELECT PRODUCT_ID, SUM(QUANTITY) FROM ORDERS
WHERE PRODUCT_ID IN 
( 
 SELECT PRODUCT_ID FROM             --product_id sold on both days
 (                
  SELECT PRODUCT_ID, DATE, COUNT(*)
  FROM ORDERS
  WHERE DATE IN ('01-JUL-11', '02-JUL-11')
  GROUP BY PRODUCT_ID, DATE
  ORDER BY PRODUCT_ID, DATE
  HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
 )
)
GROUP BY PRODUCT_ID;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
--2nd method -- Quantities sold on both days
SELECT PRODUCT_ID, SUM(QUANTITY) FROM ORDERS 
WHERE PRODUCT_ID IN
(
SELECT PRODUCT_ID FROM
(
SELECT DISTINCT PRODUCT_ID FROM ORDERS WHERE DATE  = '01-JUL-11'
INTERSECT
SELECT DISTINCT PRODUCT_ID FROM ORDERS WHERE DATE  = '02-JUL-11'
)
)
GROUP BY PRODUCT_ID
ORDER BY PRODUCT_ID;
```

Answer (score -1):

I know we can optimise it slightly, but here i what gets you the result

```
SELECT `PRODUCT_ID`, QTY FROM (
  SELECT `PRODUCT_ID`, SUM(`QUANTITY`) AS QTY, GROUP_CONCAT(`ORDER_DAY`) AS dates
  FROM ORDERS
  GROUP BY PRODUCT_ID) AS tmp
WHERE dates LIKE '%02-JUL-11%' AND dates LIKE '%01-JUL-11%'
```

UPDATED, no subqueries

```
SELECT `PRODUCT_ID`, SUM(`QUANTITY`) AS QTY
FROM ORDERS
WHERE `ORDER_DAY` IN ('01-JUL-11', '02-JUL-11')
GROUP BY PRODUCT_ID
HAVING GROUP_CONCAT(`ORDER_DAY`) LIKE '%01-JUL-11%' AND GROUP_CONCAT(`ORDER_DAY`) LIKE '%02-JUL-11%'
```

Answer (score -1):

**Here is a more generic working solution. Try this out:**

```
select product_id ,sum(quantity) as total from ORDERS where product_id in  
(
select product_id from (
      select product_id,count(*) as cnt from     
        (  
          select distinct order_day,product_id from ORDERS  
        ) distinct_product_day_combination  
      group by 1   
      having cnt in    
      (select count(distinct order_day ) from ORDERS      
)  
                 )
)   
group by product_id
```

Answer (score -2):

```
select product_id ,count(product_id) from wayfair_order_tbl 
group by product_id
having count(order_day)>1
```

Comment: Where do you get `wayfair_order_tbl` from? You're also thinking that the table contains only exactly the data he shares when in reality there would be many potential days to select from. Your result includes orders made more than once and not necessarily on either of the days he's looking for.